# Palindrome Function with Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, boolean, nodes, palindrome

I made Palindrome Function For my linked list but sadly it doesn't seems it works ! , It has no syntax error i believe , the problem is logical when i run the program , It always gives me "Not Palindrome " whatever the linked list is .

here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int info;
    node *link;
};


class Linked_List
{
private:
    int count;
    node *first;
    node *last;
    node *current;

public:
    Linked_List()
    {
        count=0;
        first=NULL;
        last=NULL;
    }

    void Initialize_List()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Number OF Nodes"<<endl;
        cin>>count;

        first=last=current=new node;

        for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter New Node Info :"<<endl;
            cin>>current->info;
            last->link=current;
            last=current;
            current=new node;
        }

        last->link=NULL;
    }

    bool Is_Empty()
    {
        if(first==NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int Front ()
    {
        if (first != NULL)
            return first-> info;
        else return 0;
    }

    int Back ()
    {
        if (last != NULL)
            return last-> info;
        else return 0;
    }

    void Delete_First()
    {
        if (!Is_Empty())  // Or if(first==NULL)
        {
            node *p;
            p=first;
            first=first->link;
            delete p;
            count --;
            if (count==0)
                first=last=NULL;
        }
    }

    friend bool Palindrome();
};

bool Palindrome (Linked_List & n)
{
    {
        while (!n.Is_Empty())
        {
            if (n.Front()!=n.Back())
            {
                cout<<"Not Palindrome"<<endl;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                n.Delete_First();
                n.Delete_First();
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Palindrome"<<endl;  return true;
}


void main ()
{
    Linked_List obj;

    cout<<"Is the list empty ?"<<"  "<<boolalpha<<obj.Is_Empty(); cout<<endl;

    obj.Initialize_List();

    cout<<"Is the list empty ?"<<"  "<<boolalpha<<obj.Is_Empty(); cout<<endl;

    Palindrome(obj);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `n.Delete_First()` does, but (a) it isn't in the posted code, and (b) invoking it *twice* in succession isn't looking too good right about now. And when/if you update the posted code, **don't** hose the formatting again. It is actually *readable* now and it would be nice if it stayed that way.

Comment: @WhozCraig my apologies , i forgot the delete_first function , done adding it , what do you mean it will be readable automatically ?

It always gives error for reading code and wont post ..

Comment: Ctrl-K (Cmd-K for Mac users) does marvelous things. as does Ctrl-D in Visual Studio or simply posting code in Xcode. Live by [Henry Spencer's 8th Commandment](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html). And It looks like perreal has noted the problem I briefly mentioned in my first comment (the double-first-delete mistake). Looks like you have a good answer. excellent!

Comment: FYI, `Is_Empty()` could be rewritten as: `bool Is_Empty(){ return first==NULL; }`

Comment: Also, why the extra scope in `bool Palindrome`?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes i did ! , thanks all for helping :)

Comment: @Joce i did noticed it now , thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete one from the left side and one from the right side, and also consider the case of odd number of elements:

```
n.Delete_First();
if (!n.Is_Empty()) 
    n.Delete_Last();
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer, in particular mentioning the odd-element-count.